# sending structs over sockets

Tags: c++, vb.net, sockets, interop, struct

i am using vb.net and i would to send some structs to a C++ tcp server.

The problem is the structs i am sending might contain other structs.

Struct{
   uint length;
   byte really;
   customStruct customStuff;
}FirstStruct;

Struct{
   uint length;
   char[] name;
}CustomStruct;

Lets say i want to send FirstStruct over to the C++ Server. How do i go about doing it? Some code examples will be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Structs can't be sent over sockets, only bytes. You must decide how to convert the structures to a byte stream in the sender, and back to equivalent data structures in the receiver.

Assuming both sides are running Windows*, you can use [.NET binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28VS.71%29.aspx) to handle the details. I doubt that supports converting from a VB.NET struct directly to a C struct, but it should be able to construct a reasonable approximation on the receiving end.

* Mono, AFAIK, does not support .NET extensions to C++.

Comment: yup. i understand that i need to convert the struct to byte array before sending. The problem i am having is finding examples of doing it and also examples on how to convert a structure that contains members which is of another structure type to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize my vb structs into something like XML ( or JSON ) and parse them on the server side...

Comment: That is an existing server we are trying to connect to so changing the way it works on the data is impossible :(